# Linux scripting after opening a screen

Tags: linux, scripting, gnu-screen

In my shell script, I'm trying to open up a screen and have the script continue in the screen.  Is this possible?  Every time I open a screen, the script stops and waits for me to close out of it to continue.

```
screen -S newScreen; echo "text in screen here"
```

Answer (score 1):

I am pretty sure I start screen like this.

```
screen -t screen-name 0 command
```

In my case I start my irc client and some other stuff, the 0 is the number of the screen in the list. So if you have more increment this.

```
screen -t irc 0 irssi
```